# Is there a way to do a screenshot on android service code?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-service, screenshot

I want to do a screenshot of my phone outside the application.
I created an android service that I can run my app in the background but I didn't found any solutions to take some screenshots.

Im using Xamarin(c#).

I found a lot code to create some screenshots, but they were all related only to the application.

Here is an example:

```
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, " Downloads ");

        View v1 = Window.DecorView.RootView;

        v1.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;

        Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(v1.GetDrawingCache(true));

        Java.IO.File imageFile = new Java.IO.File(path, System.Environment.TickCount + ".jpg");
        System.IO.MemoryStream bytes = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        int quality = 100;

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path);
        if (!dir.Exists)
            dir.CreateSubdirectory(path);

        Java.IO.FileOutputStream fo;
        imageFile.CreateNewFile();
        fo = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(imageFile);

        bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, quality, bytes);
        fo.Write(bytes.ToArray());
        fo.Close();
```

Comment: Use the `MediaProjection` APIs and remember to ask for the user's permission via using `CreateScreenCaptureIntent` first.

Comment: have you found a solution ? I Have not found any working latest code. The code from microsoft is missing some files and it was few years old